# Trying to show a combobox element in a textbox in WPF of C# using selectedChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, textbox

Here is the method:

```
private void Capitales_SelectedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = Capitales.SelectedItem.ToString();
    tb.Text = "Selection: " + s;
}
```

I'm putting a list in the combobox, and when I compile the program, the textbox shows the next: ComboBox_MicroDocu.MainWindow+Ciudades, where "Ciudades" references my class.

Comment: yes, when you do SelectedItem.ToString() it is putting the string representation of the entire object into the text property.  You need to assign the desired property to the text field instead,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing WPF app as you whould do with Winform. This whould work, but there is a better way to do it. Use MVVM (Model View ViewModel).
MVVM is great since it allows you to decouple your views (xaml) from your business logic (viewModels). It's also great for testability.
Check out some good resources here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/index.htm

this is how your code should looks like :

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedElement}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _selectedElement;

    public IEnumerable<string> Elements
    {
        get
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                yield return $"Element_{i}";
            }
        }
    }

    public string SelectedElement
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedElement;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedElement = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Add more clarification to the answer, for example [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) and some description why it's better to use MVVM approach than Events.